# Find by a value in an object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't make a query to all profiles that are included in a specific department.

I'm using nodejs with mongo and mongoose. An example of a Profile schema is the next:

```
Profile: {
   "level": 1,
   "departments": [
    {
        "_id": "5c5f3bb4338fde6c60a684d4",
        "department": "5c106a324acd0571241323f2",
        "name": "Calidad"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c5f3794eca3f14cd49e395e",
        "department": "5c106bad99142733446a44f0",
        "name": "Mantenimiento"
    }
]
```

This below is the query I tried:

```
Profile.find({ departments: [{ department: req.params.id }] })
  .then(profiles => res.json(profiles))
  .catch(err =>
    res.status(404).json({ nodepartmentfound: "No departments found" })
  );
```

I expect to return tan array with all profiles with the specified department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Profile.find({ "departments.department": req.params.id })
  .then(profiles => res.json(profiles))
  .catch(err =>
    res.status(404).json({ nodepartmentfound: "No departments found" })
  );
```

Basically, what you want to do is query an array of embedded documents. Using the dot notation is enough to solve your problem. Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).